# AWS s3 expressjs file upload: upload not a function error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file with `upload` method using AWS s3 in express js http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property.

```
var params ={
            Bucket:'lambdacushbu',
            Key:req.files.image.name,
            Body:req.files.image.data
        }
        var options ={
            partSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1
        };
        s3.upload(params,options,function(err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            else     {
                console.log("uploaded",data);
                res.json({
                    'status':'Uploaded'
                });
            }           // successful response
        });
```

But i got the following error.

> s3.upload is not a function

When i try with `PutObject` method it works fine.

Comment: what's the npm package aws-sdk you are using? Pls log Object.getOwnPropertyNames(AWS.S3.Prototype) and see if it has a 'upload' property in it

Comment: Which is the correct npm aws-sdk package??

Comment: I will get the following   `cannot read the property Prototype undefined`